# Scala Play Action.async cant resolve Ok as mvc.AnyContent

Tags: scala, future, playframework-2.2

The following controller action cause the error:

```
(block: => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]  cannot be applied to (scala.concurrent.Future[Object])".
```

Every Future inside the action should be `Ok()` so I don't understand why scala can't resolve the futures correctly.

```
def form = Action.async {
  val checkSetup: Future[Response] = EsClient.execute(new IndexExistsQuery("fbl_indices"))
  checkSetup map {
    case result if result.status == 200 => Ok("form")
    case result => {
      val createIndexResult: Future[Response] = EsClient.execute(new FillableSetupQuery())
      createIndexResult map {
        indexCreated => Ok("form").flashing("success" -> "alles tutti")
      } recover {
        case e: Throwable => Ok("form error").flashing("message" -> "error indexerzeugung")
      }
    }
  } recover {
    case e: Throwable => Ok("form error").flashing("message" -> "error index query")
  }
}
```

Complete Error messages:

```
overloaded method value async with alternatives: [A](bodyParser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[A])(block: play.api.mvc.Request[A] => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult])play.api.mvc.Action[A] <and>   (block: play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>   (block: => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]  cannot be applied to (scala.concurrent.Future[Object])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where but it seems that there was a case in this action that was not covered by my case structure.
I refactored the action to this and it works fine now:

```
def form = Action.async {
  EsClient.execute(new IndexExistsQuery("fbl_indices")) flatMap { 
    index =>  if (index.status == 200) Future.successful(Ok("form"))
    else {
      EsClient.execute(new FillableSetupQuery()) map {
        indexCreated => Ok("form").flashing("success" -> "alles tutti")
      } recover {
        case e: Throwable => Ok("form error").flashing("error" -> "error indexerzeugung")
      }
    }
  } recover {
    case e: Throwable => Ok("form error").flashing("error" -> "error index query")
  }
}
```